# How to refresh page with button in js document with node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, localhost

I have tried switching the button to be above the script, and also tried making a function in the app.js file. None of these two methods work.

```
res.write("<script>" + "function refreshPage() {location.reload()}" + "</script>")
res.write('<br> <button onclick=' + '"refreshPage()">')
```

Comment: When you send a response, it will be received by the front end as text, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Refresh the page on server response ?

Comment: `button` element needs the closing tag.

Comment: What i want to achieve is to have a button on my /fact website that reloads the website when clicked, but I can't manage to change any elements, or even have an HTML doc there.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use
`window.location.reload()` to reload the page
or maybe simulate the Ctrl + R action using keydown or keypress event, I hope this was helpful

Comment: I have now tried to make a new html file for the path, but since the JS for the HTML page has to be in the public folder, I can't seem to access the "require" function from node. is there a way to use "require" in the public folder?

Comment: I don't think so, you can use "import" in platforms like Vue, React...etc but in a normal javascript I don't think you